# Replacing page functions via userscript in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, greasemonkey, userscripts

I've created a Greasemonkey script which replaces a page function:

```
(function() {
    var oldFunc = func;
    func = function() {
        oldFunc();
        // other stuff
    };
)();
```

I had always intended this script to work in both Gresemonkey and Chrome and had read that Chrome doesn't support `unsafeWindow`, so have been injecting the script into the page by converting the function to a string and using `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout("(function(){var old=func;func=function(){old();/*other stuff*/}}())", 0);
```

This works perfectly well in Greasemonkey, but gives me absolutely nothing in Chrome.  It clearly isn't firing, but nothing appears in the log, either.  I have tried a number of other injection styles, but can't get anything to work.  (For testing, I also added an `alert()` to the top of the function.)

1. `setTimeout(..., 0)` — nothing
2. Running the function in-scope, without injection into the page — no alert, but "func is not defined" in console
3. `document.href = "javascript:..."` — nothing
4. `document.body.addEventListener("load", ...)` — nothing

All of these are with `@run-at document-end`.

Unfortunately, this being my first Chrome userscript, I'm at a loss as to how to debug it, even after an hour or so of Googling and poking around SO.  Any help?

Actual script, currently working in Greasemonkey: http://pastebin.com/HtLVjYHg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, the only technique I found which worked in Chrome was to create a `<script>` node using DOM methods.  Fortunately, this seems to work equally well in Firefox and Opera and is made fairly painless by `<func>.toString()`:

```
function embed() {
   var oldFunc = window.func;

    window.func = function() {
        oldFunc();

        // other stuff
    };
}

var inject = document.createElement("script");

inject.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
inject.appendChild(document.createTextNode("(" + embed + ")()"));

document.body.appendChild(inject);
```

Final script: http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/84394