# Why don't my Greasemonkey scripts work in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My Greasemonkey scripts all work in Firefox 3.6, but in Chrome 6 nothing special happens when I load a page that is supposed to trigger them. [Here](http://drop.io/dnvqjpq/asset/hacker-news-highlight-user-js)'s an example script (pasted below) that highlights top comments on Hacker News. Can anyone identify what I'm doing wrong? When I click on the user.js file and install it in Chrome, the installation succeeds.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Hacker News highlight
// @namespace      http://news.ycombinator.com
// @description    highlights popular comments
// @include        http://news.ycombinator.com/item*

// ==/UserScript==

var GM_JQ = document.createElement('script');
GM_JQ.src = 'http://jquery.com/src/jquery-latest.js';
GM_JQ.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(GM_JQ);

// Check if jQuery's loaded
function GM_wait() {
    if(typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined') { window.setTimeout(GM_wait,100); }
else { $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery; letsJQuery(); }
}

GM_wait();

function letsJQuery() { 

    var maxScore = 0;
    var secBest = 0;
    var min = 0;

    var numComments = 0;
    $(".comhead > span").each(function() {
        numComments = numComments + 1;
        var score = parseInt($(this).text().split(' ')[0]);
        if(score > maxScore) {
            maxScore = score;
        }
        else if(score > secBest) {
            secBest = score;
        }
    });

    min = maxScore - secBest;

    $(".comhead > span").each(function() {
        var score = parseInt($(this).text().split(' ')[0]);

        if(min!=0 && score >= min + 1) {
            $(this).css({'background-color':'#B2D7FB', 'padding':'4px 4px 4px 4px','-moz-border-radius':'3px', '-webkit-border-radius':'3x'});      
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: For what its worth I have chrome 7. Is it possible that greasemonkey support was added at 7?

Comment: Does the script work for you? Greasemonkey support was added back in February.

Comment: I'm running Chromium 6.0.472.53 on Ubuntu 10.04 and GreaseMonkey scripts don't work for me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it easiest to access page resources by [injecting my code into the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542609/replacing-page-functions-via-userscript-in-chrome/3602611#3602611):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Hacker News highlight
// @namespace      http://news.ycombinator.com
// @description    highlights popular comments
// @include        http://news.ycombinator.com/item*
// @run-at         document-end
// ==/UserScript==

function letsJQuery() {
   // your stuff
}

var jQuery = document.createElement("script"),
    inject = document.createElement("script");

jQuery.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
jQuery.setAttribute("src", "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js");

inject.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
inject.appendChild(document.createTextNode("(" + letsJQuery + ")()"));

document.body.appendChild(jQuery);
document.body.appendChild(inject);
```

The `@run-at` ensures that the script loads immediately after `DOMDocumentReady`, just as in Greasemonkey, and I changed your jQuery URL to point to their CDN.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246901/include-jquery-inside-greasemonkey-script-under-google-chrome/2246934#2246934). My scripts now work.